Changing Color of FontAwesomeIcon's not working as intended?
Im trying to make a FontAwesomeIcon svg as a button, I am trying to change the color of the icon, but I am unsure why the color is not changing.
I am using react and here is a portion of my code:
import styles from './Navbar.module.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faMagnifyingGlass } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

...

                        <div className={styles.searchContainer}>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="" />
                            <button type="button" className={styles.searchButton}>
                                <FontAwesomeIcon className={styles.searchIcon} icon={faMagnifyingGlass} />
                            </button>
                        </div>

And the CSS property
/* Search button */
.searchButton {
    position: absolute; 
    right: 5px; 
    border: none; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    width: 25px; 
    height: 25px; 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* Search icon */
.searchIcon {
    color: red;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

I tried to change the color through different classes like the button, or the button class itself. The only time the color changes is from my global.css file, where I have a default color, but I might be missing on a specific way to change the svg icon's color manually

Use the inspector in your browser dev tools. Does the HTML look like intended and what styles are applied to the element? Can you see if the color in .searchIcon is overridden by something else?
